# error code in finding confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, error-message, profile-likelihood

I optimized parameters from a function using `mle2` from `bbmle` package.
After I got the values, I tried to find profile likelihood confidence interval of parameters using `confint()` but there is one parameter that I got NA in lower bound and I got a warning message.

```r
fit.LP8.2test <- mle2( lleq8.2test,  start = 
    list(k0=0.01950077, r0= 1.085169, 
          alpha =0.7443884, ds =  0.5889412, 
          di =  0.09513703), skip.hessian=FALSE, 
          optimizer =  "optimx")
a.8 <- profile(fit.LP8.2test, alpha = 0.05)
confint(a.8)
Warning message:
    In .local(object, parm, level, ...) :
      non-monotonic profile (di): reverting from 
    spline to linear approximation (consider 
    running 'profile' with manually reduced 
    std.err)
```

How can I solve this error?